# How do I make my pygame window minimze and maximize?

Tags: python, pygame, window

So I have a pygame but the screen won't get bigger nor smaller. I can't make it larger. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a resizable display, by setting the `pygame.RESIZABLE` flag, when you call [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode).

```py
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

When the size of the window is changed, then the `pygame.VIDEORESIZE` event occurs. For instance:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)

    # [...]
```

Comment: at line 14 do I have to write (in your example) 500, 500 and what should i write at event.w and event.h. And then at the next line do I have to write ((500, 500)...) to? It douesn't work

Comment: Hmmm... I don't get it. Or maybe I get it and something else doesn't work...
```
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            (width = 800,height = 600) = event.w, event.h
            win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.RESIZEABLE)
```
Is this false?

Comment: thanks it worked. but the things I added before (buttons, ground,...) wont resize like the window. It'll stay the same.

Comment: @RMR_MD Yes of course. Nothing happens automatically. You have to draw the objects dependent on the width and height of the screen.

Comment: And how do I do it. I can't figure it out

Comment: @RMR_MD Now you would need `width` and `height` again (which you didn't like before). Anyway you can get the size of the window by [`window.get_size()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_size) respectively the width and height separately by [`window.get_width()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_width) and. [`window.get_height()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_height). Recreate the buttons dependent on the current size of the window.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that it would look strange while it's minimized?

Comment: @RMR_MD No. You don't get the `pygame.VIDEORESIZE` event on  minimize. The event occurs only on resize and maximize (fullscreen). Minimize just "hides" the window.

Comment: I am sorry if I bother you. I'm just a beginner and don't find the tutorials I need (mostly) and don't get answers else either.

Comment: @RMR_MD I recommend the sites [PyGame - tutorials](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials) and [Pygame Front Page](https://www.pygame.org/docs/). In the light green area at the top of "Pygame Front Page" you can select different pygame modules and find the API documentation to different topics. The pygame API documentation is well structured and very detailed.

Comment: I can't find anything usefull. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: I didn't find anything usefull sadly. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @RMR_MD What to do? Do you want to create a scalable button? The title of this question is  *"How do I make my pygame window minimze and maximize?"*. I recommend to add a new question and to explain where you stuck. Please note the comment section is not intended for additional question. [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a give all contributors the chance to give an answer and to receive reputation.